# Active Record can't read flashdata PHPCI

Tags: php, activerecord, continuous-integration

i have problem with active record. when i use flashdata into activerecord. the activerecord always return error. i don't know why that happened.. please help me guys! :D

there is my code

```
$query2 = $this->session->flashdata("sQuery");      
return $this->db->query($query2)->result_array();
```

when i echo $query2.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS PublisherName,Address,City,Telephone,Fax,Email FROM MsPublisher WHERE AuditActivity NOT IN ('D') AND DATE_FORMAT(CreatedTime, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '07/01/2013' AND '11/30/2013' ORDER BY `PublisherName` asc
```

}

and when i submitted $query2 into active record. it always return error like this

```
The query you submitted is not valid.
```

if I run the query in mysql. can run successfully.. is there something wrong with my code?

thanks.